# Styling nested UL with same class

Tags: css, nested, html-lists

I have a nested list and I'm having trouble styling the last level UL.

```
<ul class="same-class">
    <li>
        <ul class="same-class">
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I need is to display the first UL items inline, and below them show their children as blocks.  The problem is both UL have the same class (I can't change the HTML output, nor add classes), and I can't find the proper selector to target the second UL.

[In the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/7q947g1m/) I tried adding a diferent class to menu 3 and 4, and that does the trick, but since changing class isn't an option I need to find a workaround to make the children display as blocks.

Can someone take a look and advise?

Comment: Do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/7q947g1m/2/?

Comment: Yes! I was so fixed on targeting the UL that I forgot about the LI's. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul ul li { display: block; }` or `.same-class .same-class li {  display: block; }` should do the trick - that'll select all `li` that are a child of two or more  `ul` or `.same-class`

[This might be useful (attribute selectors)](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) depending on what your real code looks like (most likely useful if you're using AngularJS or something similar) or [the `nth-child` might be good too](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/) because I'm not 100% sure what you mean.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you was to use CSS parent selectors then try;

```
ul.same-class li {
   display: inline-block;
}

li > ul.same-class li {
   display: block;
}
```

The `>` in the second rule will select all `ul.same-class li` elements where it has a `li` as a parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you try plugging this in, you should be able to target the various components as you like.
The first selector is targeting all list items that are direct children of the first menu.
The second one is targeting any lists inside of a list item which itself is a direct decendant of the menu class.
The third one is targeting just your list items in your nested lists.  It gives a good degree of control for adjusting the layout.

```
ul.menu:first-of-type > li{
    display:inline-block;
}

.menu > li ul {
    display:block;

}
.menu:first-of-type > li > ul > li {
    display:block;
}
```